# Slim download csv with UTF-8 BOM

Tags: php, slim

I'm trying to generate and download a csv file in utf-8 with BOM, I'm trying like this:

```
$response->getBody()->write(chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF)); // BOM sequence

$response->getBody()->write(implode(';', $headers) . PHP_EOL);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $response->getBody()->write(implode(';', $row) . PHP_EOL);
}

return $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/force-download')
    ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
    ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/download')
    ->withHeader('Content-Description', 'File Transfer')
    ->withHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary')
    ->withHeader('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename=" . uniqid())
    ->withHeader('Expires', '0')
    ->withAddedHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0')
    ->withHeader('Cache-Control', 'post-check=0, pre-check=0')
    ->withHeader('Pragma', 'public');
```

The file downloads successfully, but without BOM.

How can I correctly write the characters for BOM in the response?

Comment: When I run your code, it works as expected. The download file contains the BOM sequence. How do you check the binary content of the file?

Comment: I opened the file with notepad++, and from menu, plugin -> hex editor -> view in hex